# upgrade bootstrap 3.3.3 glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use the new glyphicons that are in bootstrap-sass version 3.3.3.  Or bootstrap version 3.3.2.  I upgraded to the latest but the new glyphicons will not display.  I can do this and it displays fine  `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>`  but if i do this `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i>` it shows nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: "I can do this and it displays fine but if i do this it shows nothing." <- huh??

Comment: Use Markdown to properly format your code next time

Comment: Did you upgrade both the fonts and the CSS?

Comment: If i use glyphicon-chevron-right  it shows up fine.  If i use glyphicion-menu-right it does not show up.  I am using ruby on rails so I updated my Gemfile. Then did bundle install.  This is what I put in the Gemfile:          gem 'bootstrap-sass',  '3.3.3'

Comment: I found the problem  in my Gemfile i had  gem 'bootstrap-sass',  '~>3.3.3'. This will not upgrade due to the Gemfile.lock.  Second I ran assets-precompile.. should not had to do that on development server. I removed the tmp/cache  stopped the server. Started the server and they showed up.  Thanks!!!!